# ( jQuery Pjax ) and WordPress

Tags: jquery, wordpress, pushstate, pjax

when using AJAX in WordPress, All the AJAX requests should be sent to wp-admin/admin-ajax.php file to process then this file will return the appropriate result

I want to use PJAX with WordPress but I do not know how it will send the ajax requests to admin-ajax.php file,  I cant see any options for this

Comment: Why do you want to use PJAX? It's no longer being maintained and hasn't been for 5 years. What is your end goal? What does PJAX offer that jQuery `.ajax` does not?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I want to use pjax to change page url without loading the page and add url to the history, jquery ajax does not do that